# how to encode data from database into a qr and then retrieve same data using a specific android application connected to your web based application

Tags: php, android

Am a novice,and am trying to make this web based application in php that stores data to mysql database and then creates a qr code image for every entry.i want also to query this data using using a specific android application by scanning the embedded qr code.how will the two application connect.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic & http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - We're here for specific programming problems, not to answer such questions. We'll not google for you. Please ask this kind of questions anywhere else. If you're stuck with programming, you're welcome to come back here and ask us about. Then simply follow the guide on "how to ask" - show us what you've tried so far, share your thoughts with us and we'll help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Helo there,

You can create a unique id for each entry in database and save The QRCode image on server. You can use [Endroid QRCode PHP Library](https://github.com/endroid/qr-code) for creating QRCode images. Now the android app should be able to scan the QR Code and When QR Code is detected it should call the webserver with the QRCode data. You should match this data with id in your database and return the results.